# SignalR Authentication on Method not Hub

Tags: signalr, owin, signalr-hub, signalr.client, bearer-token

I am using an OWIN Auth2.0 Authorization Server for Authorizing users and generating Tokens. How can I Connect to a Hub without any Authentication, but prevent anonymous users to call some Methods.

Authentication to FooHub is not required.

Authentication to FooHub.FooMethod is required.

Authentication to FooHub.FooBarMethod is not required.

### Edit

I have everything exact like in this question [SignalR AuthorizeHubConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28275341/signalr-authorizehubconnection) ,and i got the same problem. Everytime i want to set the "server.User" variable, i get an NullReferenceException.

Comment: If you are using bearer tokens, are you even able to authorize entire hubs? How do you plan to use the token to authenticate SignalR hubs/methods?

Comment: I am sending the token as a header ("Authorization") to the Server.

Comment: And did you manage to decode the token and authorize hubs?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40873774/12534) will explain and resolve NullReferenceException.